# PHPMailer Connection error

Tags: php, phpmailer

i got an error with my php mailer. It says: "Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed." I tried these smtp settings on a wordpress newsletter plugin, and they worked there, so i dont know why this dont work. The port need to be 587, because of my host.

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                  // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.mysite.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->port = "587";  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'my@mail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*******';                           // SMTP password

$mail->From = 'my@mail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'My name';
$mail->addAddress($row['email'], $row['name']);     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
}

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.<br>';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

Comment: did u add `//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and try

Comment: I talked to my host and they said, that they dont recommend that..

Comment: Wait, they don't recommend using encryption? Oo

Comment: PHP is case sensitive: `port` should be `Port`.

Comment: Also you need to set `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try this code based on same PHPMailer class:

...

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail -> IsSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;

$mail -> Host = 'mail.mysite.com';
$mail -> Port = "587";

$mail -> Username = 'my@mail.com';
$mail -> Password = '*******';

$mail -> SetFrom('my@mail.com', 'My name');
$mail -> AddReplyTo('my@mail.com', 'My name');
$mail -> AddAddress($row['email'], $row['name']);

$mail -> Subject = $subject;
$mail -> MsgHTML($body);

if (!$mail -> send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.<br>';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail -> ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```